# views_embed_view is overriding the output in hook_services_views_execute_view_alter

Tags: views, hooks, services

I'm working with Drupal 7.x with services 3.x and views 3.x module, below is the code which I've in my custom module. When I'm executing the same, views_embed_view() overrides the output of the whole view and displays only those values that are called by using views_embed_view(), any suggestion on this?

```
function module_services_views_execute_view_alter(&$output, $view) {
  if ($view->name == 'web_services' && $view->current_display == 'articles') {
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
      // I'm getting only this output
      $value->relatedArticles = views_embed_view('web_services', 'related', 140, 120);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine, try print $output at the end of hook to confirm it has proper data.

Comment: your `view->current_display` is suppose to be `==` to your **[machine name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)** ie: `'block_1'`